# Code to have browser choose Flash player first, then fall back to HTML5 video

Tags: html, flash

I'm just making video on my site HTML5 compliant for portable iOS devices and one thing I'm running into is that I would like to have the client browser try the Flash player first because it's more customizable and if Flash is unavailable, try HTML5.

I had thought that maybe the order in the video tag would do it but it always goes to HTML5 regardless of the order of the tags.

For example:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
     <object width="640" height="360"><embed src="flashplayer.swf?movie=movie.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="360"></embed></object>
     <source src="/video/ogg/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     <source src="/video/mp4/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SwfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to detect Flash, and put the video element in the div that SwfObject replaces if Flash is available.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with JavaScript?  I don't want to use the SwfObject.

Comment: Yes, you can do the same kind of stuff that SwfObject does in your own JavaScript if you prefer (since SwfObject is JavaScript). Before SwfObject, it was quite common to do Flash detection in your own scripts, but since it can be quite messy and SwfObject does it well, SwfObject has become more or less de facto standard for doing it.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks.  I was hoping there was something that was single-line or something like that as I want to use this code in a phpBB forum and not have to alter all the themes to include a reference to the SWFObject but it doesn't sound like that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

To do it without Javascript, I think you could put the `<video>` tag inside the `<object>/<embed>` to act as fallback if the browser cannot execute the object, i.e. the Flash player plugin is not available:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
    <embed src="flashplayer.swf?movie=movie.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="360">
        <video width="640" height="360" controls>
            <source src="/video/ogg/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            <source src="/video/mp4/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </embed>
</object>
```

Note that you can do it with a pure `<object>` tag, no need for `<embed>` in most modern browsers, AFAIK.

Comment: I could be off my rocker, but I'm pretty sure this is the cleanest way to do this. :)

Comment: I really like this solution. Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [HTML 5 video player widget](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/video_player_widget.html) that that is based on the [Kaltura](http://www.kaltura.org/project/HTML5_Video_Media_JavaScript_Library) open source library. It will let you customize both the HTML 5 as well as the Flash video player.

Comment: Interesting but I am looking for something ultra-lightweight, like possibly doing it just with HTML tags or if I have to a simple "if" statement with JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to show Flash when user has it you will need some way to detect it. I think normally the detection happens by trying to run a SWF and seeing the results. If you don't want all the customization, consider SwfObject suggested by @Lars.